# How to cut the space of the closing in moderncv cover letter?

Tags: moderncv, letters

I am writing a cover letter using `moderncv`. The problem is when executing the latex file I get two pages with only my name in the second page. I would like to cut the space between `sincerely` and `my name`. How to do this ?

```
\makeletterclosing
```

will produce for example

```
Sincerely
   | 
   |
   |---------------------> How to cut the space or make it small
   |                       so that my name can be in the first page?          
   |
My name
```

Comment: `\makeletterclosing` is redefined according to the style provided in `\moderncvstyle`. I didn't check the other styles, but with `classic`, it suffices to use `\usepackage{xpatch}` and then patch `\xpatchcmd{\makeletterclosing}{[3em]}{[1em]}{}{}`. The default space is `3em`, I made it `1em`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<sub>From my comment to a proper answer. `:)`</sub>

`\makeletterclosing` is redefined according to the style provided in `\mderncvstyle`. I didn't check the other styles, but with `classic`, it suffices to patch the command and add the desired space.

Let's say we want to have `1em`. We can patch `\makeletterclosing` with `xpatch` (my favourite package):

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\makeletterclosing}{[3em]}{[1em]}{}{}
```

Or we can rely on `etoolbox`, which is already loaded by `moderncv`:

```
\patchcmd{\makeletterclosing}{[3em]}{[1em]}{}{}
```

Then we are have:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}

%\usepackage{xpatch}
%\xpatchcmd{\makeletterclosing}{[3em]}{[1em]}{}{}

\patchcmd{\makeletterclosing}{[3em]}{[1em]}{}{}

\firstname{Donald}
\familyname{Duck}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\recipient{Uncle Scrooge}{}
\opening{Dear Uncle,}
\closing{Yours sincerely,}

\makelettertitle

\kant[1]

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: Quack]

Yay! `:)`